# Read message lag in Spring Kafka: consumer starts read message from retry topic instead main topic

Tags: java, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

**KafkaProducerConfiguration.java:**

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory(KafkaProperties kafkaProperties) {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> applicationIdKafkaProducer(ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory) {
        KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);

        kafkaTemplate.setObservationEnabled(true);

        return kafkaTemplate;
    }
}
```

**KafkaConsumerConfiguration.java:**

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers}")
    private String kafkaBootstrapServer;

    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}")
    private String kafkaGroupId;

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> applicationIdConsumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> kafkaConsumerConfigurationProperties = Map.ofEntries(
                new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaBootstrapServer),
                new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, kafkaGroupId)
        );

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(kafkaConsumerConfigurationProperties, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> applicationIdKafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

        factory.getContainerProperties().setObservationEnabled(true);
        factory.setConsumerFactory(applicationIdConsumerFactory());

        return factory;
    }
}
```

**KafkaRetryConfiguration.java:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafkaRetryTopic
public class KafkaRetryConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public RetryTopicConfiguration applicationIdRetryTopic(@Value("${application.kafka.topic}") String topic,
                                                               @Value("${application.kafka.topic.retry.attempts}") Integer attempts,
                                                               @Value("${application.kafka.topic.retry.delay}") Integer delay,
                                                               @Value("${application.kafka.topic.retry.multiplier}") Integer multiplier,
                                                               KafkaTemplate<String, String> applicationIdKafkaProducer) {
        return RetryTopicConfigurationBuilder
                .newInstance()
                .maxAttempts(attempts)
                .exponentialBackoff(delay, multiplier, delay * (long) Math.pow(multiplier, attempts - 1))
                .notRetryOn(List.of(
                        DeserializationException.class, MessageConversionException.class, MethodArgumentResolutionException.class,
                        NoSuchMethodException.class, ClassCastException.class, java.lang.IllegalStateException.class
                ))
                .includeTopics(Collections.singletonList(topic))
                .create(applicationIdKafkaProducer);
    }
}
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=PLAINTEXT
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=http://localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=refusal-application-filter-group
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest

application.kafka.topic=RAF.APPLICATION.IN
application.kafka.topic.retry.attempts=5
application.kafka.topic.retry.delay=2400
application.kafka.topic.retry.multiplier=5
```

**@KafkaListener method:**

```
    @KafkaListener(
            id = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}",
            topics = "${application.kafka.topic}",
            containerFactory = "applicationIdKafkaListenerContainerFactory"
    )
    public void listenApplicationId(@Header("kafka_original-topic") String topic,
                                    @Header("retry_topic-attempts") Integer attempt,
                                    @Headers MessageHeaders messageHeaders,
                                    String applicationId) throws CustomWrongResponseException {
        log.info("Message '{}' was received from topic {}, attempt: {}", applicationId, topic, attempt);

        try {
            applicationService.sendApplication(applicationId);

            log.info("Processing message '{}' from topic {} is finished", applicationId, topic);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Process message id '{}' from topic {} is violated:", applicationId, topic, e);

            throw e;
        }
    }
```

**Created topics** (there is one partition everywhere):

```
RAF.APPLICATION.IN-0
RAF.APPLICATION.IN-dlt-0
RAF.APPLICATION.IN-retry-2400-0
RAF.APPLICATION.IN-retry-12000-0
RAF.APPLICATION.IN-retry-60000-0
RAF.APPLICATION.IN-retry-300000-0
```

**Environment:** Java 17, Spring Boot 3.0.6, WildFly 28.0.0, Kafka 2.13 - 3.3.2

My goal - consumer reading message from topic `RAF.APPLICATION.IN-0` without big delay (< 1 second, in first time).
But for some reason consumer reading first retry-topic `RAF.APPLICATION.IN-retry-2400-0` instead main-topic `RAF.APPLICATION.IN-0`.
Accordingly, a delay of 2.4 seconds is obtained.

**Logs:**

```
2023-10-23 07:57:34.013 INFO  [default task-1] [traceId=ae165306b0b90bee753bfcb7883fff18, spanId=3357f33254026b7b] ru.naysav.raf.service.ApplicationService: Message '39f78426-8dee-4629-9759-000000000022' successfully produce to topic RAF.APPLICATION.IN
...
2023-10-23 07:57:34.709 INFO  [refusal-application-filter-group-retry-2400-0-C-1] [traceId=ae165306b0b90bee753bfcb7883fff18, spanId=0e34de57c8add6cf] org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer: [Consumer clientId=consumer-refusal-application-filter-group-retry-2400-1, groupId=refusal-application-filter-group-retry-2400] Seeking to offset 0 for partition RAF.APPLICATION.IN-retry-2400-0
2023-10-23 07:57:36.628 INFO  [refusal-application-filter-group-retry-2400-0-C-1] [traceId=ae165306b0b90bee753bfcb7883fff18, spanId=eff2518344cd8116] ru.naysav.raf.api.listener.ApplicationIdListener: Message '39f78426-8dee-4629-9759-000000000022' was received from topic RAF.APPLICATION.IN, attempt: 2
```

At the same time, there is a message in the main-topic `RAF.APPLICATION.IN-0`:
[Offset explorer screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Suy0.png)

**Additionally: topic `RAF.APPLICATION.IN-retry-1500000-0` was not created, although 5 attempts were indicated**

Comment: What you are suggesting makes no sense; there is a separate listener container for each topic; they are independent. Please provide an [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that exhibits this behavior. Also `maxAttempts` is total attempts (including the first) so 4 retries only.